# Rails and Postgres problem querying record that was stored in UTC; app Timezone is UTC but record is not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I have a Rails 5 app with default Timezone settings (UTC).
I have a record that was created on `Thu, 08 Aug 2019 02:12:56 UTC +00:00` but the app is being accessed by someone located at Central Time which means the record was created for them on `Wed, 07 Aug 2019 20:12:56 CST -06:00`; The app provides a filter and this user is trying to retrieve records from `08/07/2019` and is expecting that this record would be part f the resulting set, date filter is being passed as a Date object.

I have tried several forms to convert this Date object into a form that when passed down to the query it successfully returns the expected results. Note: `filter.end_date` is an instance of Date with value `"Wed, 07 Aug 2019"`

Query:

`Record.where("records.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", filter.start_date.beginning_of_day, filter.end_date.end_of_day)`

SQL:

```
Record Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE (records.created_at BETWEEN '2019-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-07 23:59:59.999999')
```

The only way that I have achieved this is when I set Timezone to central time and then pass the query:

This is working

```
Time.use_zone("Central America") { Record.where("records.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", date_filter.end_date.beginning_of_day, date_filter.end_date.end_of_day) }
```

SQL:

```
Record Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE (records.created_at BETWEEN '2019-08-07 06:00:00' AND '2019-08-08 05:59:59.999999')
```

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the necessity to set a Timezone per user within the app and just do the correct conversion when passing down the date provided in the filter.

Comment: How are you setting the filter?  Is it some kind of date range picker on the front end?

Comment: Yes, the front-end is using a date range picker

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you or are you still running into problems? If there are more issues, you can edit you question to give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to ignore the timezone.

If you are getting the users timezone on sign up you could add something like `Time.zone(current_user.timezone) if current_user` into a before action callback or some other initial startup sequence. The has the disadvantage of making the value mostly static, ie if they are traveling and are in a different timezone your results will still be for your "home" timezone unless you add that as an option in their profile etc.

Alternatively you could set the current timezone dynamically using javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("submit", function(event) { // listen to all submit events
    var form = event.target.closest('form');
    var timezoneInput = form.querySelector('input[name=timezone]');

    if (timezoneInput) { 
            timezoneInput.value = moment.tz.guess(); // assuming you are using a time library
    }  
});
```

And handle that in your controller:

```rb
def index
    Time.use_zone(params[:timezone]) do
        @records = Record.where("records.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", date_filter.end_date.beginning_of_day, date_filter.end_date.end_of_day)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a database solution (which is commendable since you use `timestamp with time zone`), just set the `timezone` parameter for the database session to the current time zone of the user. Then everything should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Whether or not you should store user's timezone in the DB depends on how often you will need to show times in a specific timezone.  Best practice is to set your application to use the time zone where **most** of your users are.  If you have not already, you probably want to set this application.rb for example:

```
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

For complete list you can run `rake time:zones:all`

Now make sure you always use zone.  Anywhere in your application you will want to replace `Time.now` with `Time.zone.now`  and `Date.today` with `Date.current`  or better `Time.zone.now.to_date`.

If in your case you just want to filter records timestamps (i.e. `created_at`) I'm guessing you use some kind of datetime picker on the front end in a form etc.  There is likely an option to add the users's browser's time offset.  Here's an example of using jQuery datetimepicker.  The additional format option is `O`

```
$(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
      timepicker: true,
      format: 'm/d/Y H:i O',
      maxDate: '0'
    });
})
```

Now you will have the datetime with timezone offset value which you can use in your database query.  You'll be able to do something like this rough example.

```
start_time = Time.zone.parse(params[:start_time].to_s)
end_time = Time.zone.parse(params[:end_time].to_s)
Record.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', start_time, end_time)
```

I would also recommend checking out this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised), old but relevant.